# Specifying Input/Output dimensions for CoreML 2 model with Flexible Shapes

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I managed to create a CoreML 2.0 model with flexible input/output shape sizes:

[image]

I can't figure out how to set the size in my Xcode project, however. If I set the input pixel buffer size 2048x2048, the output pixel buffer is still 1536x1536. If I set it to 768x768, the resulting pixel buffer is still 1536x1536 - but is blank outside the region of 768x768.

I examined the automatically generated Swift model class and don't see any clues there.

I can't find a single example anywhere showing how to use the "Flexibility" sizes.

In the WWDC 2018 Session 708 "What's New in Core ML", Part 1 it states:

> This means that now you have to ship a single model. You don't have to have any redundant code. And if you need to switch between standard definition and high definition, you can do it much faster because we don't need to reload the model from scratch; we just need to resize it. You have two options to specify the flexibility of the model. You can define a range for its dimension, so you can define a minimal width and height and the maximum width and height. And then at inference pick any value in between. But there is also another way. You can enumerate all the shapes that you are going to use. For example, all different aspect ratios, all different resolutions, and this is better for performance. Core ML knows more about your use case earlier, so it can -- it has the opportunities of performing more optimizations.

They say "we just need to resize it". It so frustrating because they don't tell you how to just resize it! They also say "And then at inference pick any value in between" but offer no clue how to pick the value in between!

Here is how I added the flexible shape sizes:

```
import coremltools
from coremltools.models.neural_network import flexible_shape_utils
spec = coremltools.utils.load_spec('mymodel_fxedShape.mlmodel')
img_size_ranges = flexible_shape_utils.NeuralNetworkImageSizeRange()
img_size_ranges.add_height_range(640, 2048)
img_size_ranges.add_width_range(640, 2048)
flexible_shape_utils.update_image_size_range(spec, feature_name='inputImage', size_range=img_size_ranges)
flexible_shape_utils.update_image_size_range(spec, feature_name='outputImage', size_range=img_size_ranges)
coremltools.utils.save_spec(spec, 'myModel.mlmodel')
```

Here is the description of the model:

```
description {
  input {
    name: "inputImage"
    shortDescription: "Image to stylize"
    type {
      imageType {
        width: 1536
        height: 1536
        colorSpace: BGR
        imageSizeRange {
          widthRange {
            lowerBound: 640
            upperBound: 2048
          }
          heightRange {
            lowerBound: 640
            upperBound: 2048
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  output {
    name: "outputImage"
    shortDescription: "Stylized image"
    type {
      imageType {
        width: 1536
        height: 1536
        colorSpace: BGR
        imageSizeRange {
          widthRange {
            lowerBound: 640
            upperBound: 2048
          }
          heightRange {
            lowerBound: 640
            upperBound: 2048
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are two layers using "outputShape":

```
layers {
    name: "SpatialFullConvolution_63"
    input: "Sequential_53"
    output: "SpatialFullConvolution_63_output"
    convolution {
      outputChannels: 16
      kernelChannels: 32
      nGroups: 1
      kernelSize: 3
      kernelSize: 3
      stride: 2
      stride: 2
      dilationFactor: 1
      dilationFactor: 1
      valid {
        paddingAmounts {
          borderAmounts {
          }
          borderAmounts {
          }
        }
      }
      isDeconvolution: true
      hasBias: true
      weights {
      }
      bias {
      }
      outputShape: 770
      outputShape: 770
    }
  }
  ...relu layer...
  layers {
    name: "SpatialFullConvolution_67"
    input: "ReLU_66"
    output: "SpatialFullConvolution_67_output"
    convolution {
      outputChannels: 8
      kernelChannels: 16
      nGroups: 1
      kernelSize: 3
      kernelSize: 3
      stride: 2
      stride: 2
      dilationFactor: 1
      dilationFactor: 1
      valid {
        paddingAmounts {
          borderAmounts {
          }
          borderAmounts {
          }
        }
      }
      isDeconvolution: true
      hasBias: true
      weights {
      }
      bias {
      }
      outputShape: 1538
      outputShape: 1538
    }
  }
```

I am now trying to figure out how to remove the outputShape from those two layers.

```
>>> layer = spec.neuralNetwork.layers[49]
>>> layer.convolution.outputShape
[1538L, 1538L]
```

I tried setting it to []:

```
layer.convolution.outputShape = []
```

To a Shape:

```
layer.convolution.outputShape = flexible_shape_utils.Shape(())
```

Whatever I try, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Can't set composite field
```

Do I have to create a new layer and then link it to the layer that is outputting to it and the layer it is outputting to?

Comment: Is there a layer inside the model that always resizes to 1536x1536, rather than to the shape of the input image?

Comment: Yeah, there are two layers using fixed outputShapes. See edit above. Is there any way to make those use the shape range? Note that I used torch2coreml to convert the model from torch7.

Comment: Good question. You'd first have to find out if the model even works with image sizes other than 1536x1536. But according to the Core ML specification, if you unset the outputShape on those layers then the output shape is calculated automatically. (You'd have to do this by loading the Core ML model into a "spec" object with coremltools, then removing the outputShape from those layers, and saving the spec back to an mlmodel file.)

Comment: Awesome thanks! Yeah, the model definitely works at whatever size I set for it. The layer SpatialFullConvolution_63 is set to half the size. Is there a way for the shape to be automatically calculated at half size? Could you give me a hint what the command names are t remove the shape from the layers perhaps as an answer that I could then accept?

Comment: I edited my post to show how I am trying to remove outputShape from the layers.

Comment: I was able to delete the outputShape with `del layer.convolution.outputShape[:]`, and the model now works at any resolution, thank you! My only concern, is I am wondering what is happening with the layer that was previously half the shape size, is that now running out the full shape size? Anyhow, if you want to post an answer showing how to delete the layer (can use my code) I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: It will automatically compute the output size based on the padding and stride settings, I believe. So in theory it should do the correct thing. In the Xcode build pane you can see the shapes of the layers as the image is being compiled, although I'm not sure what this shows when you're using flexible shapes.

Comment: It is almost working perfectly, but the padding is somehow not quite right. The output buffer is always 3px smaller in both the X and Y dimensions, and scaling the buffer up doesn't align with the original. Going crazy trying to figure out the recipe for aligning them! I'm not sure what you mean by the Xcode build pane, do you mean where the Buildtime messages are displayed?

Comment: Like this: http://machinethink.net/images/peek-inside-coreml/BuildLog@2x.png

Comment: Thanks for that! So it does show shape sizes, they are based on the minimum size set for the flexible shape size; very helpful thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this case was that there were layers present in the model that used a fixed shape for their outputShapes. For example:

```
>>> layer = spec.neuralNetwork.layers[49]
>>> layer.convolution.outputShape
[1538L, 1538L]
```

The model in question was indeed fully convolutional, so before converting to CoreML, it worked with any input and output shapes.

I was able to delete the fixed outputShape with this command:

```
layer = spec.neuralNetwork.layers[49]
del layer.convolution.outputShape[:]
```

After doing that, the model worked with flexible input and output shapes.

All credit for this answer goes to Matthijs Hollemans.